# Generating custom script for model input using R

Tags: r

I’m using R to prepare data to input into a model (written in Fortran, compiled into an .exe).

The model requires a text file as input which I'm generating using R. In the end it’s mostly just a list of variables (like ‘VARIABLE_X = 0.6’). The value of these variables is based on some processing I'm doing in R. An example on how the generated text file partly looks like;

```
GWLI = -124.4
SWSP = 0
FREXP = 0.9
```

In which for example GWLI is established by some processing using a function and stored into a string.

Currently I'm storing these in a vector using;

```
variables = c(paste0("GWLI = ", GWLI), paste0("SWSP = 0"), paste0("FREXP = 0.9"))
```

Which is wrapped by a function with no input arguments, stored as a variable and written to a file

```
script.function = function(){
variables = c(paste0("GWLI = ", GWLI), paste0("SWSP = 0"), paste0("FREXP = 0.9"))
}

run = scrip.function

write(run, "input.file.swp")
```

My first question is if there is a better way to do this? To generate such scripts using R with more straightforward programming? Not only because this feels like a bit work around-ish, but also because I run into problems in some situations.

For example, I have these daily files from a .csv file which I have processed (or any other tabular format I'm ending up with) and I need them to end up in the script in this form:

```
date, B51A1839
2015-01-01, 833.825
2015-01-02, 832.804166666667
2015-01-03, 832.554166666667
2015-01-04, 829.908333333333
```

This is basically a csv file output. However, I need it to end up in this format in the same script file I'm generating at a specific place in the script file so it kind of ends up like this:

```
GWLI = -124.4
date, B51A1839
2015-01-01, 833.825
2015-01-02, 832.804166666667
2015-01-03, 832.554166666667
2015-01-04, 829.908333333333
SWSP = 0
FREXP = 0.9
```

Anybody who has any idea how I can achieve this? How I can generate such a script using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following function is what the question asks for.

```
write.special <- function(outfile, GWLI, SWSP, FREXP, data){
  of <- file(outfile, "wt")
  on.exit(close(of))
  txt <- sprintf("GWLI = %f\n", GWLI)
  cat(txt, file = of)
  write.table(
    x = data, 
    file = of,
    append = TRUE, 
    quote = FALSE,
    sep = ",",
    dec = ".",
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = FALSE
  )
  txt <- sprintf("SWSP = %f\n", SWSP)
  cat(txt, file = of, append = TRUE)
  txt <- sprintf("FREXP = %f\n", FREXP)
  cat(txt, file = of, append = TRUE)
  invisible(NULL)
}

flname <- "~/tmp/stefaneke.txt"
write.special(flname, GWLI, SWSP, FREXP, df1)
```

---

If the character strings `variables` are already formed (with `paste0`) the function can be slightly changed to this version:

```
write.special2 <- function(outfile, vars, data){
  of <- file(outfile, "wt")
  on.exit(close(of))
  txt <- sprintf("%s\n", vars[1])
  cat(txt, file = of)
  write.table(
    x = data, 
    file = of,
    append = TRUE, 
    quote = FALSE,
    sep = ",",
    dec = ".",
    col.names = TRUE,
    row.names = FALSE
  )
  txt <- sprintf("%s\n", vars[2])
  cat(txt, file = of, append = TRUE)
  txt <- sprintf("%s\n", vars[3])
  cat(txt, file = of, append = TRUE)
  invisible(NULL)
}

write.special2(outfile = flname, vars = variables, data = df1)
```

---

In both cases the output is the same.
The contents of the output file `"stefaneke.txt"` are below. Note the extra decimal digits in `GWLI`, `SWSP` and `FREXP`. This can be changed with other formats of `sprintf`, if needed.

```
GWLI = -124.400000
date,B51A1839
2015-01-01,833.825
2015-01-02,832.804166666667
2015-01-03,832.554166666667
2015-01-04,829.908333333333
SWSP = 0.000000
FREXP = 0.900000
```

---

### Data

```
GWLI <- -124.4
SWSP <- 0
FREXP <- 0.9

df1 <- read.csv(text = "
date, B51A1839
2015-01-01, 833.825
2015-01-02, 832.804166666667
2015-01-03, 832.554166666667
2015-01-04, 829.908333333333
")
```

Comment: Your comment has helped me a lot! Especially linking the code to a file with the 'outfile' argument. Thanks!